# Loading chunk 3 failed.$(error: ......js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chunks

I am working in Vuejs for my web application. During testing phase, it works perfectly. However, logrocket always show me the following eror

Error: Loading chunk failed.

May i know why logrocket shown me this issue? How to fix it?